# Bootstrap Side by Side buttons in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make two buttons that are side by side to go into a table that I'm displaying through a PHP file called within a Javascript, however I cannot get the buttons to go side by side correctly. I've tried various things people previously suggested, but with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
$data .= '<tr><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.$row['forename'].'</td><td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['joined'].'</td><td>'.$row['rank'].'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" onClick="ChangePassOpen(\''.$row['username'].'\')">Change Password</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" onClick="ChangeRankOpen(\''.$row['username'].'\')">Change Account Rank</button></td></tr>';
```

Or view webpage (Hit Go to show the table) http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/admin/accountlist.php

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Well `btn-block` appears to be your problem, as it sets the buttons to display block and the width to 100%.

Comment: try to redefine style for `btn-block` as follow: `.btn-block+.btn-block {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: Chris that seems to have worked well, thanks. Mind posting it as a answer so I can flag it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs"
```

**btn-block** class is going to make your buttons take up 100% of the space available and block the entire row ([Bootstrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#sizes)), so nothing else fits in it.

1. Remove the `btn-block` class
2. Add some css style rules to make the buttons more distinguishable and fit in better. I'd suggest adding some padding or a margin between the buttons.

Comment: It seems that the extra buttons has shifted the rest of the table to the right and created a large blank space on the right. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Easiest & fastest way is to limit the column width `<td style="width: 250px"><button [...]`. Or you can do `<td class="button-cell">` and in your css file: `.button-cell { width: 250px; }`. Tinker with the 250px as needed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/admin/accountlist.php I've placed width: 150px in the table header and each row, but it's not adjusting the table collum width.

Comment: No space between the number and px. E.g. this is good: `250px`, this ain't: `150px`

Comment: * `150 px` this ain't